# Shinydashboard box() masked by graphics package in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, package, shinydashboard

I am trying to create boxes for my shiny app but I believe the `box()` function from `shinydashboard` is being masked by the `box()` function from `graphics` package.

Here is a very simple reproduction of my problem with a screenshot of what my box looks like. I've included the packages that I use in my actual shinyapp in case that is important, but they aren't used in this reproduction. I have tried running it with `shinydashboard::box()` but that didn't work either.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
 })

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("title panel"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel("Sidebar"),
            mainPanel(
                shinydashboard::box(title = "Box Fail.", status = "primary", background = "red")
            )) ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

``
[![shiny screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a17d2.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useShinydashboard()` from `shinyWidgets` package

> **Description**
>
> Allow to use functions from 'shinydashboard' into a
>   classic 'shiny' app, specifically valueBox, infoBox and box.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){})

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinydashboard(),
    titlePanel("title panel"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("Sidebar"),
      mainPanel(
        shinydashboard::box(title = "Box Fail.", status = "primary", background = "red")
      )) ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Well that is an extremely helpful package! Thanks Pork Chop.